# Linking two UIScrollViews so they follow each others touches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, hyperlink, mirror

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connect two UIScrollView's together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489165/connect-two-uiscrollviews-together)

I want to make a list, that is divided in 2 parts, left and right. The left part can only scroll vertically (has a list in it). The right part scrolls vertically, and horizontally..

So, I want a control that has a list on the left side, and a view on the right side, both detect scrolls. But the left part always stays on the screen, and only moves vertically, the right part may scroll left and right as well.. I hope you understand this :p..

The way I thought I would do it, was:
- Make 2 scrollviews
- Subclass both scrollviews and catch touches
- Mirror the touches to the other scrollview

And then just turn off horizontal scrolling on the left Scrollview..
HAHA, I'm wrong, Apple seems to have turning off catching events on UIScrollView classes since OS 3.0..

Has anyone got another idea on how to do this, except for writing a completely custom control that handles it's own scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

Could you put a transparent view on top of both scrollviews that passes touch events to both?