# Connect two UIScrollView's together

Tags: iphone

Here's a tricky iPhone problem I've been working on. I have three UIScrollViews on a page, one that only scrolls horizontally, one that only scrolls vertically, and one that scrolls both horizontally and vertically. I want to lock the views together, so that the horizontal location of the horizontal only scrollview matches the horizontal location of the main scrollview, and the vertical scrollview likewise, so that dragging the main scrollview around controls the horizontal and vertical scrollviews.

Problem is, I'm completely stumped. I've looked around inside the apple documentation, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this officially. One thought that I had was to somehow "clone" any touch on any of the scrollviews to a point on the other two, but I have no idea how to do this. If anyone has any thoughts on this, I'd very much appreciate it.

Edit: I tried the suggestion of subclassing UIScrollView and overriding touchesMoved to call touchesMoved on the other scroll views. Unfortunately, touchesMoved doesn't get called for scrolling motions as UIScrollView intercepts those motions somehow and uses them to control its scrolling. I started looking around more low level stuff and found the core animation scroll layers, but ideally I wouldn't want to recreate UIScrollView from scratch. Still trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to add a delegate to your scrollviews which implement the following method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Then you can check the contentOffset to check by how much the scrollview did actually scroll, and update the main scrollview accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. I feel a bit dumb now, but thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Am stunned at how seamlessly this actually works. I'd thought of it but expected the bounces etc to not be reflected and it look icky. It's perfect. Thanks Martin!

Answer (score -1):

You need to extend UIScrollView for all three uses on your screen and override the touchesMoved:withEvent: methods to call the other ones (make sure you don't end up with circular code that ends up calling itself again!).

So, for example the code in the two-way scrolling item could be based on this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [horizontalScrollview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [verticalScrollview touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

by using some additional variable (eg `ControllerLastTouched`) you can check that before calling the other two touchesMoved:withEvent: methods.

This should enable you to do the "cloning" you were talking about...

Comment: Hey, so I thought this was what I was looking for but it turns out stuff is a bit more complex than I thought. When I set up this arrangement, any touches to the view contained within the UIScrollView get picked up, but scrolling motions themselves don't call touchesMoved. I'm pretty sure this is due to the way UIScrollView works - they start a timer upon finger touchdown, and if the person scrolls within a certain amount of time it starts the scrolling motion, else it passes the touch on to the touch handling methods of the view.